# How can I change the font and font size of the RDA arrows - ggvegan?

Tags: r, rda

I'm making an RDA, and I can not change the information it returns me, as font and font size. I would like to change the font of the arrows and the size of the letters is this possible?
I marked the information I want to change with a red circle, to make it easier to understand.
[image]

I used this code to generate the image I indexed. And what I would like to do is change the formatting (font and font size) of the names indicated by the RDA arrows.

```
library(devtools)
library(ggvegan)


p2=autoplot(rda1, arrows = FALSE,axes = c(1, 2), geom = "point","text", layers = c("sites", "biplot", "centroids"))+
  geom_point(data = dd2,aes(RDA1,RDA2,shape = site1,colour = site1),size=3)+
  ylim(-3,3.0)+ xlim(-4,4.0)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0,slope = 0,linetype="dashed", size=0.8)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0), linetype="dashed", size=0.8)+
   labs(x = "Axis 1 (13.8%)", y="Axis 2 (2.9%)")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)+
  theme(legend.justification = c(0,0),
        legend.position = c(.10,.07),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "Times",  colour = "black", size = 20),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Times", size = 25),
        text = element_text(family = "Times", size = 20));p2
```

Comment: Please show your code, and tag the package you used to make this graphic. See [ask] and [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)